# Find Meeting Times returns AttendeesUnavailable with bigger timeslot

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to test my queries. I am invoking findMeetingTimes POST request.

Firstly, I am running it with these time constraints:

```
"timeConstraint": {
    "timeslots": [
      {
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "2017-05-23T09:00:00",
          "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "2017-05-23T12:00:00",
          "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
      }
    ]
```

This returns me correctly several meeting options.
However, if I change the start time from 9 o'clock to 8 o'clock (which should increase the number of options available) I get the `AttendeesUnavailable` as the `emptySuggestionsReason` instead of at least the same amount of meeting proposals like in the former request.

What could be a cause of this? Is it a bug?
The remaining parameters of the query were simple two attendees, one location, and a duration of one hour.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your message. There are a couple of reasons the API could've returned AttendeesUnavailable on the second request.  Attendee's could have created or accepted new events on their calendars, making them busy for the desired dates or maybe the list of attendees was different between requests?

If you have confirmed none of this is true, then I could look at the logs to see if there is a problem with the API.  For this though I would need you to go to the "Response Headers" tab in graph explorer and send me the value of the "request-id" header.

Comment: Thank you @user8038869 for the reply. The state of the attendees and location was still the same (it was just for testing purposes) and I replicated the result many times. 

So the correct request and client request ids are as follows:

`client-request-id: b46accf2-dd33-4491-9cca-bb9b2beb88d1`
`request-id: b46accf2-dd33-4491-9cca-bb9b2beb88d1`.

The incorrect request and client request ids are as follows:

`client-request-id: 4c273395-0142-4599-b59b-563f80935ded`
`request-id: 4c273395-0142-4599-b59b-563f80935ded`.

Many thanks for looking into this!